# Alternating groups and linear groups

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

I learned from the literature that the symmetric group $S_n$ can be viewed a subgroup of permutation matrices of $GL_n(q)$ (where $q$ is a prime power), the general linear group of invertible $n\times n$ matrices over a field of order $q$. Therefore $A_n$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $SL_n(q)$. Can you help me to understand what happens when we go to $PSL_n(q)$? Is $A_n$ still a subgroup of $PSL_n(q)$?

Comment: What is $q$?  Could you please introduce it to us?

Comment: $q$ is just a prime power. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Ok, so I guess the answer is the same for any field $F$.  The image of $S_n$ in $GL_n(F)$ has trivial intersection with the center, which gets to be moded out in the passage to $PGL_n(F)$.  Therefore both $A_n$ and $S_n$ survive the passage to the quotient meaning that their representation in $PGL_n(F)$ is faithful.

Comment: Let me just add that the key here is that $\operatorname{PGL}_n(F) \cong \operatorname{GL}_n(F)/Z$, where $Z$ is the center, i.e. scalar matrices, and the only permutation matrix that is scalar is the identity matrix. Passing to $\operatorname{PSL}_n(F)$, the argument remains the same since adding the requirement that determinant is $1$ does nothing to what we are doing.